# Logger Output in C# .NET test

Tags: c#, .net, logging, xunit

I have in my .NET Solution a xunit project and try to get my logger outputs to show in the console in an easy way. To notice the infos and errors in the `dotnet test` run. I need to understand why a test passes locally but fails on my CI server and would like to have the logger output shown in the console.

I can achieve that, but IMO in a painful way. My test Looks as follows:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

public class UnitTest3
{
    private ILogger<UnitTest3> _logger;

    //Configure the logger
    private ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

    public UnitTest3(ITestOutputHelper outputHelper)
    {
        _loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddConsole();
            builder.AddProvider(new TestOutputLoggerProvider(outputHelper));
            builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
        });
        _logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<UnitTest3>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MyTest_Method_Should_Log_Messages()
    {
        // Log some messages
        _logger.LogInformation("Information message");
    }
}
```

The only way how I could make it work is by having my Custom ILoggerProvider that does the following:

```
public class TestLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _outputHelper;

    public TestLoggerProvider(ITestOutputHelper outputHelper)
    {
        _outputHelper = outputHelper;
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return new TestOutputLogger(_outputHelper);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // No resources to dispose
    }
}

public class TestOutputLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _outputHelper;

    public TestOutputLogger(ITestOutputHelper outputHelper)
    {
        _outputHelper = outputHelper;
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return null; // No scope support in this example
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return true; // Enable all log levels
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        // Write log message to the output helper
        _outputHelper.WriteLine(formatter(state, exception));
    }
}
```

and then executing with

```
dotnet test --logger "console;verbosity=detailed"
```

To get an output.

I am really confused why not adding the Console logger with `builder.AddConsole();` does not do the trick. Comming from the Java world I am missing something here, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: That's how xUnit works. Check [Capturing Output](https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output) `If you used xUnit.net 1.x, you may have previously been writing output to Console, Debug, or Trace. When xUnit.net v2 shipped with parallelization turned on by default, this output capture mechanism was no longer appropriate`

Comment: Besides, if your application is using ILogger or the generic host, you do need to create either the host or the logger factory. You can't create a console logger directly. There's `NullLogger` to act as a mock

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for your comment That is really confusing for me coming from the Java Spring world :). There would be some spring package to do this dirty work for you. After moving in circles with ChatGPT it finally suggested to me the  ILoggerProvider with the logger flag.

I could not see any popular post about that, so it is maybe not a common usecase.

Comment: ChatGPT answered with what you asked, not the real answer. `coming from the Java Spring world` what does that mean? log4j output isn't sent to the console by default, it's sent to the loggers you defined. You don't write straight to the console, you use a logger or nowadays, OpenTelemetry traces. And once again, that's just how xUnit works. NUnit captures the output. xUnit doesn't.

Comment: I had no clue before about the IloggerProvider, I was arround in the dark ^^, until something useful came for a change...

Good comment with the host, I am able to inect my provider in the tests using:

` var collection = new ServiceCollection();
   collection.AddLogging(builder => { ... }`
and using the provider to get logger service.

Comment: Or you can use `var builder=Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);` to create a host builder with DI, console*debug logging and JSON config predefined and start it with `var host = builder.Build();`. If you register your classes/services, `var myService=host.Services.GetRequiredService<MyService>();` will give you a service with the ILogger injected.

Comment: As for why xUnit acts this way, it was written back when console output on Windows was a *lot* trickier. The way it runs parallel tests is causing problems nowadays. For example [Playwright offers support classes for NUnit and MSTest but not xUnit](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/test-runners) because xUnit can't handle resources shared among concurrent tests.